# Can function of _targets.R read object from targets list?

Tags: r, targets-r-package

## Problem

Using `targets` package in `r`, we make functions and targets obejcts in `_targets.R` file. In a function, I want to calculate something not just based on the input obejects but also based on the objects in the global environment. However, seems that it doesn't work in this way.

## What I have done

I will give two example, showing how we write code without and with `targets` package. The first one runs without problem, but the second code doesn't work due to the problem I mentioned above.

The first example. Let's start from a empty project folder. I make a new R script, and this is how we do generally without using `targets` package.

```
# a function to sum 2 values then minus 1
fun_sum_1 <- function(x, y) {
  res <- sum(x, y) - 1
  return(res)
}
my_x <- 2
my_y <- 3
my_res <- fun_sum_1(my_x, my_y)
my_res
# [1] 4
```

Then I do almost the same thing using `targets` package. Firstly, make a new R script and name it "_targets.R". Write the following code in this `_targets.R` and save the file.

```
library(targets)

# a function to sum 2 values then minus 1
fun_sum_1 <- function(x, y) {
  res <- sum(x, y) - 1
  return(res)
}

# targets list
list(
  tar_target(my_x, 2), 
  tar_target(my_y, 3), 
  tar_target(my_res, fun_sum_2(my_x, my_y))
)
```

Then we run the `_targets.R` in console pannel with the following code.

```
library(targets)
tar_make()
```

You will see the progress of the runing. The difference between this and general practice above is that there is not "my_x" or "my_y" or "my_res" or "fun_sum_1" showing up in the environment pannel. Then we load the results to our global environment by runing the following code in the console pannel.

```
tar_load(my_res)
my_res
# [1] 4
```

And if we run `tar_visnetwork()`, we can see a flowchart of the target obejcts.

Then we go to the second example, the example with problem. First, we write code as usual.

```
# clean the global environment first
rm(list = ls())

# a function to sum 2 values and 1 existing value of global environment then minus 1
# it differs from fun_sum_2 that it doesn't only rely on input obejects
# but also the "my_z" in the global environment
fun_sum_2 <- function(x, y) {
  res <- sum(x, y, my_z) - 1
  return(res)
}
my_x <- 2
my_y <- 3
my_z <- 4
my_res <- fun_sum_2(my_x, my_y)
my_res
# [1] 8
```

Now we try to make this using `targets` package. We revise the `_targets.R` into the code below, and save the file.

```
library(targets)

# a function to sum 2 values then minus 1
fun_sum_2 <- function(x, y) {
  res <- sum(x, y, my_z) - 1
  return(res)
}

# targets list
list(
  tar_target(my_x, 2), 
  tar_target(my_y, 3), 
  tar_target(my_z, 4), 
  tar_target(my_res, fun_sum_2(my_x, my_y))
)
```

Then we run the following code in console pannel. But then error happens.

```
library(targets)
tar_make()
# ✔ skip target my_x
# ✔ skip target my_y
# ✔ skip target my_z
# • start target my_res
# ✖ error target my_res
# • end pipeline [0.095 seconds]
# Error:
#   ! Error running targets::tar_make()
# Error messages: targets::tar_meta(fields = error, complete_only = TRUE)
# Debugging guide: https://books.ropensci.org/targets/debugging.html
# How to ask for help: https://books.ropensci.org/targets/help.html
# Last error: object 'my_z' not found
```

Though I make a `my_z` in the targets list, but seems that `fun_sum_2` can't read it. Of course, I can make `my_z` an input into the `fun_sum_2` function, which will solve the problem. However, what if I have a function relying on many objects in the global environment?

I wonder how can I solve this problem without making `my_z` one of the inputs for the `fun_sum_2` function.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to function scope or environment. You should know that your function `fun_sum_2()` is defined in the global environment, within which you cannot find an object named `my_z`. To make it work, you should move your definition of `my_z` to the global blocks, too. The following codes should work:

```r
targets::tar_dir({
  targets::tar_script({
    library(targets)
    
    # a function to sum 2 values then minus 1
    fun_sum_2 <- function(x, y) {
      res <- sum(x, y, my_z) - 1
      return(res)
    }
    my_z <- 4
    
    # targets list
    list(
      tar_target(my_x, 2), 
      tar_target(my_y, 3), 
      tar_target(my_res, fun_sum_2(my_x, my_y))
    )
  })
  targets::tar_make()
})
#> ▶ start target my_x
#> ● built target my_x [0 seconds]
#> ▶ start target my_y
#> ● built target my_y [0.015 seconds]
#> ▶ start target my_res
#> ● built target my_res [0 seconds]
#> ▶ end pipeline [0.062 seconds]
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

For more about environment, you can read [this part of the book written by Hadley](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html#function-environments).